# How to retrieve users top score from Game Center with swift

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I would like to retrieve last score to add it to my current play time score. I've tried using

```
delegate.onLocalPlayerScoreReceived(leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore)
```

But it isn't working. I had an error on this part says that unresolved identifier delegate

```
let leaderboardRequest = GKLeaderboard() as GKLeaderboard!
if leaderboardRequest != nil
{
    leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler({ (scores:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            //handle error
        }
        else
        {
            delegate.onLocalPlayerScoreReceived(leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore)
        }
    })
}
```